# How to get all the data from mysql using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

As you can see inside my while loop i declare i variable $TYPES..

This is my first Query

```
    $first = "SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(z.DatePaid,'%M %d, %Y') AS Paid 
    FROM tblStudPayments z 
    INNER JOIN tblPersonalData p ON p.StudNo=z.StudNo
    WHERE z.StudNo=p.StudNo AND z.SY='".$SY."' AND z.Sem='".$Sem."' ORDER BY z.DatePaid;";

    $fs = safe_query($first);
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($fs);
    if($numrows>0)
    {
    while($dataf = mysql_fetch_assoc($fs))
    {
        $types =$dataf['Paid']; 

    }
    }
```

I wanted to pass the value of $TYPES to my second Query

And This is my Second Query

```
     $sql="SELECT DISTINCT p.StudNo, p.LName, p.FName, p.MName, p.NName, c.Description, p.YearLevel, d.Status, 
         '".$types."' AS DateEnlisted, 

        FROM tblPersonalData p 
        INNER JOIN tblStudPayments sp ON sp.StudNo=p.StudNo AND sp.SY='".$SY."' AND sp.Sem='".$Sem."' 
        INNER JOIN tblStatusHistory d ON d.StudNo=sp.StudNo AND d.SY=sp.SY AND d.Sem=sp.Sem 
        INNER JOIN tblCourses c ON c.CourseCode=d.CourseCode AND c.HSOrCollege='".$dType."' 
        INNER JOIN tblUserAcct u ON u.UserName=p.StudNo

        "; 


        $sql.=" HAVING DateEnlisted = '".$a['DateEnrolled']."' ";
        $sql.=" ORDER BY p.StudNo ASC;";
```

At the bottom of SELECT Statement you can see my variable $TYPES i get it from my first query.

The problem is it doesn't get all the data.. it only get the last data from mysql

Thanks in Advance..
[Image Suggested by Kundu Updated][1]

[Image Suggested by Kundu echo $sql][2]

[i try one query but the loading of data takes 10-15MIN.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjgiU.png)

Comment: You have declared $types  as variable and assigning values to it through loop.So only last value will be assigned.Declare $types  as array to store all values it it.

Comment: Why not simply have one query ?!?!

Comment: I already Try it Like the photo below my question the output is correct but the problem is the loading of data takes 10-15minutes..

Answer (score 0):

In your while loop you put the value in a variable & evry time this variable is updated.So at the end of the loop it will return last `type` value. Either put it in a array, so it will store all the value.But that case you need to convert the array into string when you put it in 2nd query.Also make sure when you put value in `$type` it should be unique.

update your code like this:

```
$types=array();
 while($dataf = mysql_fetch_assoc($fs))
 {
      $types[] = $dataf['Paid']; 

 }

$allTypes = implode(",`", array_unique($types));
```

Now in your query:

```
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT p.StudNo, p.LName, p.FName, p.MName, p.NName, c.Description, p.YearLevel, d.Status, 
         `".$allTypes."` AS DateEnlisted, 

        FROM tblPersonalData p 
        INNER JOIN tblStudPayments sp ON sp.StudNo=p.StudNo AND sp.SY='".$SY."' AND sp.Sem='".$Sem."' 
        INNER JOIN tblStatusHistory d ON d.StudNo=sp.StudNo AND d.SY=sp.SY AND d.Sem=sp.Sem 
        INNER JOIN tblCourses c ON c.CourseCode=d.CourseCode AND c.HSOrCollege='".$dType."' 
        INNER JOIN tblUserAcct u ON u.UserName=p.StudNo

        ";
```

Comment: i make this in my while loop in my first query...    $types = array();                                                                                                 $types = $dataf['paid'];                                                                                                Can you tell me how can i put the variable $types in my second query..          I try to put it like this $types but its the same output                                            And I also try this $types[] i get an error..

Comment: you want to show all the values of `$type` in your 2nd select query? If yes, then after the `while` loop  declare a variable like `$allTypes`  so:  $allTypes = implode(",",$types); & in your query use the `$allTypes` instead of `$type`

Comment: i try it but it also gets the latest data from mysql.. And i discover something i try to echo the variable $TYPES inside the While Loop And The Output is All the same... i check the connection and my database the data is different from each other..

Comment: i try it and the output is just a line like this _________

Comment: print_r($allTypes) after the `while` loop & post it.

Comment: is this the result of `
print_r($allTypes)`

Comment: Yes..@Dipanwita Kundu

Comment: It seems to me there is new line character in your `$dataf['Paid']`, so you want to show all these dates in your query? If yes, then echo the 2nd query in browser & post it here.

Comment: Yes but not all this dates, Only The dates that is equal to the Value of DateEnrolled..... DateEnrolled is an array..

Comment: Then echo the 2nd query in browser & post it here.

Comment: I post the image at the bottom of my question @Dipanwita Kundu

Comment: i post it again at the bottom of my question

Comment: I just want to view  the  sql  query of `{"$sql="SELECT DISTINCT p.StudNo, p.LName, p.FName, p.MName, p.NName, c.Description, p.YearLevel, d.Status, 
         `".$allTypes."` AS DateEnlisted, 

        FROM tblPersonalData p 
        INNER JOIN tblStudPayments sp ON sp.StudNo=p.StudNo AND sp.SY='".$SY."' AND sp.Sem='".$Sem."' 
        INNER JOIN tblStatusHistory d ON d.StudNo=sp.StudNo AND d.SY=sp.SY AND d.Sem=sp.Sem 
        INNER JOIN tblCourses c ON c.CourseCode=d.CourseCode AND c.HSOrCollege='".$dType."' 
        INNER JOIN tblUserAcct u ON u.UserName=p.StudNo

        "; }`

Comment: above query where did you use the variable $allTypes?

Comment: look at the updated image ... i put the wrong image..sorry my bad

Comment: just  echo the $sql & post the output of this from browser. I want to see the exact query

Comment: ok done..just look below my question...By the way thank you for your effort and time for helping me..Thanks.

Comment: Your query is seems to ok...As per the query it checks only single date value.... Now check the logic why this returns the blank value.

Comment: i think its not blank _________  its a texts... a very small texts the allTypes Value..so the second Query output become 0 because the value of first query is so many dates... which is DateEnlisted or $allTypes.... And the value of DateEnrolled value is only one date... So they are not match

Comment: as per your query value must be a single  date,but it returns comma separated a long string.so update your logic/approach

Answer (score 0):

Put the 2nd query inside the 1st query

```
 while
```

loop

Comment: i already try it .... the loading of the data is too slow it takes 10-15minutes..